# CharSets supported in android 4.2.1

Tags: java, android, native

I'm getting following exception on  `android 4.2.1` device : nexus 7

> java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp858
>   at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:303)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android documentation has a list of guaranteed [Character Sets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), The guaranteed ones are:

- ISO-8859-1
- US-ASCII
- UTF-16
- UTF-16BE
- UTF-16LE
- UTF-8

You can also use [availableCharsets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets()) to get a list or [isSupported(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#isSupported(java.lang.String)) to check for specific sets.

Answer (score 0):

You have any code to show us the exact problem?  I believe you have to set the Charset (e.g. ISO-8859-1, utf-8, or etc)